# Get mechanize to go through x amounts of links and get all the titles?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Basically I want to use mechanize to go through all the pages from a-z on this site
http://www.tv.com/shows/sort/a_z/

then, for each letter get the title of every show on all the pages for the letter "a". At the moment I am just trying to get it to work with the letter "a". This is what I have so far but don't know where to go from here?

```
require 'mechanize'

agent=Mechanize.new
goog = agent.get "http://www.tv.com/shows/sort/a_z/"
search = goog.link_with(:href => "/shows/sort/a/").click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use some [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to find content you need and navigate.

```
require 'mechanize'
shows = Array.new
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get 'http://www.tv.com/shows/sort/a_z/'
agent.page.search('//div[@class="alphabet"]//li[not(contains(@class, "selected"))]/a').each do |letter_link|
  agent.get letter_link[:href]
  agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').each { |show_link| shows << show_link.text }

  while next_page_link = agent.page.at('//div[@class="_pagination"]//a[@class="next"]') do
    agent.get next_page_link[:href]
    agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').each { |show_link| shows << show_link.text }
  end
end

require 'pp'
pp shows
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I outputted it to a text file and got around 62k results, much more then I thought. It only took about 3 minutes aswell. Thanks for taking the time to write that out for me

Comment: Here's what `//div[@class="_pagination"]//a[@class="next"]` would look like with css: `.pagination .next` - Better?

Comment: @taro How to get the href from that iteration if my html contains <a href="http://someurl.com" title="title">wqer23</a>

Comment: @Arihant Godha Something like `my_document.at('//a[@title="title"]')[:href]`