# Clicking through google pages with mechanize

Tags: ruby, loops, mechanize

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `link_with` function in Ruby's `mechanize` gem. I've got the basic concept down:

```
page = <site>
blah blah blah
next_page = page.link_with(:text => "Next")
page = link.click
```

However it seems that when I use this with a little test, it goes very slowly, what I'm tying to do is loop through the first ten pages of google using a `loop do` with a little `time` variable to count down from 10, when the `time` variable hits 0 I want the program to break out of the loop. It seems like it's working, but it only pulls the first link off of google and just sits there.

Source:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'uri'

SEARCH = "test"

@agent = Mechanize.new
page = @agent.get('http://www.google.com/')
google_form = page.form('f')
google_form.q = "#{SEARCH}"
url = @agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)
  url.links.each do |link|
    if link.href.to_s =~ /url.q/
      str = link.href.to_s
      str_list = str.split(%r{=|&})
      urls = str_list[1]
      urls_to_log = URI.decode(urls)
      puts urls_to_log
      time = 10
      loop do
        next_page = page.link_with(:text => 'Next')
        page = link.click
        time -= 1
      end
      if time == 0
        break
      end
    end
  end
```

I found a bit of a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732239/get-mechanize-to-go-through-x-amounts-of-links-and-get-all-the-titles). However it doesn't really explain it in terms that I understand.

What am I doing wrong to where this just sits on the first link, and goes nowhere?

Comment: Have you looked into using the Google APIs? Odds are good they'll ban your IP if you're scraping their pages.

Comment: I'm not worried about the ban I have ways around that, I'm just trying to figure out how to click through the links.

Comment: Lots of confusion here. `next_page` is a link, not a page so I would start with sorting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do to follow `Next` links is something like:

```
while page = page.link_with(:text => 'Next').click
  # do something with page
end
```